# #2000 - LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is forbidden, check mysqli.allow_local_infile

Tags: php, mysql, csv, load, local

I would like to run command on MYSQL to load csv data into database:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'XXX.csv'
```

Then I got this error:

```
#2000 - LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is forbidden, check mysqli.allow_local_infile
```

I uses MySQL version 5.5.62 , php version 7.3.3.13

I have `mysqli.allow_local_infile = On` and my.cnf `local-infile=1`

Is there anything else to enable Load data working ?

Comment: Look `SELECT @@secure_file_priv;`

Comment: /var/lib/mysql-files/ . It means this must be changed ?

Comment: This means that the file which you want to import must be placed in this directory strictly. I.e. `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/XXX.csv'`

Comment: Oh thanks, now it is more clear for me to understand how it works. And this path cant be changed ? I can not find any file on server where the "secure_file_priv" is declared.  My meaning was the customer send .csv file on ftp and I load it directly from this location.  It is not possible to reconfigure files location ?

Comment: No I tryed to move files to "/var/lib/mysql-files/XXX.csv" and also got this error "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE forbidden"

Comment: *And this path cant be changed ?* This is system variable which is not dynamic (cannot be changed "on the fly"). You must edit your .INI file and restart mysql.

Comment: *I tryed to move files to "/var/lib/mysql-files/XXX.csv"* If so why do you use LOCAL if a file is local ALREADY? use `LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/XXX.csv'` simply. If the problem remains then try the same command via CLI mysql client. If success then that is not MySQL problem but PHP (?) problem.